# How to modify Android shortcut title?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-shortcut

In an app like WhatsApp, where we can add shortcuts for individual chats, group chats etc.,. When the Chat title is changed, it is not reflected to the shortcut title. The old title remains the same.

**New Shortcut create for the group chat New Name:**

[image]

**The shortcut icon added:**
[image]

**The group title is changed to New2name :**
[image]

**But the shortcut title is not modified to the new title (i.e) New2name**
[image]

**Is there a way to fix this from the developer side?**

Comment: Could you please post the screenshot of your issue

Comment: @ManojPerumarath no it's a different question. Kindly see the updated question.

Comment: @GaneshSuriya understood, i'll post the answer

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager.html#updateShortcuts(java.util.List%3Candroid.content.pm.ShortcutInfo%3E))
Using this method you can actually update an existing shortcut parameters.public boolean

```
updateShortcuts (List<ShortcutInfo> shortcutInfoList)
```

> Update all existing shortcuts with the same IDs.

[Here's an excellent article for that](https://medium.com/@andreworobator/implementing-android-app-shortcuts-74feb524959b)